# Can we prioritize animations in a web page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

If i am having 2 animations happening on a click, can we prioritize which animation to happen first.

Both animations are orthogonal. I would like to prioritize one animation after the other.

Is there any way?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay one of the animations for a number of seconds:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

If you combine that with `animation-duration`, you can make sure that the second animation starts after the first one has finished.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can apply the animations to different events, such as onmousedown/onmouseup to control which triggers first.

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp

Comment: It might be better to link to the Mozilla Developer docs. They are pretty rad and helpful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown

Comment: Ah, okay really good suggestion I'll keep in mind for next time. Thank you! :) @mk.